# Articles within Trending Articles component in Kokua it's not getting updated based on the number of recent views

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

Articles component in the Kokua is not getting updated even when some articles are getting more views than others.

1. Massive click 10 knowledge articles.
2. Check the Kokua template's Trending Articles component.
3. View the article that isn't displayed in the 5 articles in the component.
4. The article never gets displayed in the trending articles.

Is there a setting for this to check if it is working at all?

Comment: the Koa and Kokua templates were retired in summer 17, is this for a production environment? have you considered switching to Napili ? do you have the same behavior in Napili's trending article component?

Comment: Yes we have Kokua in Production already. We can't change to Napili as it has none of the componets we need for a knowledge management system (we have actually completed a study in combination with SF) and Kokua wont be removed until late 2019, so we hope the lightning componets we want (left-hand Navigation, facet search filtering, multiple trending topics etc) will be available in the Napili template, but at the moment, its not a viable template to use for a pure knowledge management UI

Comment: when you say getting updated, do you mean without reloading the page or even after reload?